# iPhone UINavigationBar change font style for all controllers with [UINavigationBar appearance]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar

I'm aware that I can individually change the font of a navigation bar as outlined in this answer: [Change the navigation bar's font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832036/change-the-navigation-bars-font)

Currently I'm using a more global approach:

```
//in my app delegate:
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

Is there a way to globally change the font that the Navbar through the appearance object?

thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412010/how-to-chage-the-color-of-text-in-uitabbaritem-in-ios-5 Similar one. :p

Comment: BTW, keep in mind, it only works for iOS5.0.

Comment: So long as you aren't changing nav bars (pushing doesn't change the nav bar, just the view), then applying the font in one class, applies it to the whole bar.  However, if using multiple bars, dearchiving a value from an NSUserDefault might not be such a bad idea.  (in fact, now that I think about it, registering a default might be the only sure way).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From Ray Wenderlich:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5

```
// Customize the title text for *all* UINavigationBars
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], 
    UITextAttributeTextColor, 
    [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8], 
    UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
    [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)], 
    UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, 
    [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:0.0], 
    UITextAttributeFont, 
    nil]];
```

Comment: Suggest use dictionary literals @{key1:object1, key2:object2,...} for better code readability.

Answer (score 20):

@Javy's answer with @Philip007's suggestion:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
                            UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                      UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8],
                     UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)],
                                 UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:0.0f]
 }];
```

*ahh... that's better!*

Comment: The font that is created has a size of 0.0f. Should that really be the case?

Comment: This was added by @runmad in the edit: "You shouldn't use font sizes, it'll set it automatically". Perhaps he can explain?

Answer (score 6):

Above answers with updates for deprecated keys and use of `NSShadow`:

```
NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 0.0;
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 2.0);
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
                     NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor],
                                NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:0.0f],
                              NSShadowAttributeName : shadow
}];
```

Also setting the font size to 0 so it automatically resizes based on navigation bar  orientation/height.