# Change UINavigationBar font properties?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, fonts, uinavigationbar, title

I have an UINavigationBar added to my UIViewController view. I want to change the fonts properties. Note that I want to change a UINavigationBar not controller. In my app where I use UINavigationController I use `self.navigationItem.titleView = label;` to display the custom label.

How can I accomplish to have a custom title in my UINavigationBar?

P.S I use this to set the title text `self.navBar.topItem.title = @"Information";` of my UINavigationBar.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

From iOS 5 onwards we have to set title text color and font of navigation bar using titleTextAttribute Dictionary(predefined dictionary in UInavigation controller class reference).

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: 
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
        [UIColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, 
           [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:16.0], NSFontAttributeName,nil]];
```

The below tutorial is the best tutorial for customization of UIElements like UInavigation bar, UIsegmented control, UITabBar. This may be helpful to you

> http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5

Comment: @rolandjitsu you just have to use NSFontAttributeName instead of UITextAttributeFont.

Comment: @CedricSoubrie ~ yes, that is true, just wanted to inform the author about that so we can have an updated answer :)

Comment: And UITextAttributeTextColor should be replaced with NSForegroundColorAttributeName

Answer (score 22):

<strike>(This is not possible using the new iOS 5.0 Appearance API).</strike>

**Edit:**

iOS >= 5.0 :

Set the Title Text Attributes for the Navigationbar:

```
// Customize the title text for *all* UINavigationBars
NSDictionary *settings = @{
    UITextAttributeFont                 :  [UIFont fontWithName:@"YOURFONTNAME" size:20.0],
    UITextAttributeTextColor            :  [UIColor whiteColor],
    UITextAttributeTextShadowColor      :  [UIColor clearColor],
    UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset     :  [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetZero]};

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:settings];
```

iOS < 5.0

UINavigationItem doesn't have a property called label or something, only a titleView. You are only able to set the font by setting a custom label as this title view 
You could use the following code: (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832036/change-the-navigation-bars-font))

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"YOURFONTNAME" size:20.0];
label.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
label.text = self.title;  
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;      
[label release];
```

Comment: Indeed, thank you for the comment. I couldn't find it at the time.

Answer (score 7):

Just put this in your app delegate's

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

From Ray Wenderlich:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], 
UITextAttributeTextColor, 
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8], 
UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)], 
UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, 
[UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiSC-Light" size:0.0], 
UITextAttributeFont, nil]];
```

Comment: Dont set size 0 to your font, that will cause visual errors when you push to a view controller. First when you push the font will have size 0 and then it will size itself appropriately but it still is visible -and annoying. Set it to 18.0

Answer (score 5):

In iOS8 swift, use the following code to set font:

```
var navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
let font = UIFont(name: "Open Sans", size: 17)
if let font = font {
    navigationBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

link below will help you.
It depends on where would you like to set font properties on current viewController's navigation bar all anywhere in application

you can find nice tutorial here%
http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/?utm_campaign=iOS_Dev_Weekly_Issue_118&utm_medium=email&utm_source=iOS%2BDev%2BWeekly

The basic idea is to create NSDictionary instance and fill it with your desired font and other properties.
I finished with this solution:

in your -viewDidLoad controller method after [super viewDidLoad] put this lines:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
NSShadow *shadow = [NSShadow new];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"EnterYourFontName" size:20.0]
shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor greenColor];
shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 2;
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);

//fill this dictionary with text attributes
NSMutableDictionary *topBarTextAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    //ios 7
topBarTextAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = color;
    //ios 6
topBarTextAttributes[UITextAttributeTextColor] = color;
    //ios 6
topBarTextAttributes[UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset] = [NSValue valueWithCGSize:shadow.shadowOffset];
topBarTextAttributes[UITextAttributeTextShadowColor] = shadow.shadowColor;
    //ios 7
topBarTextAttributes[NSShadowAttributeName] = shadow;
    //ios 6
topBarTextAttributes[UITextAttributeFont]   = font;
    //ios 7
topBarTextAttributes[NSFontAttributeName]   = font;

//for all the controllers uncomment this line
//    [[UINavigationBar appearance]setTitleTextAttributes:topBarTextAttributes];

//for current controller uncoment this line
//    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = topBarTextAttributes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add the font to your target.

I did everything that can be done about a font and I couldn't load it, when , in fact the font wasn't a member of my target.

So check Target Membership as well on the custom font added.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 13 and Swift 5.

For setting the title color & font just add in *viewDidLoad()* the following line:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.white, 
    .font: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 24)! ]
```

For setting the bar button item text color & font:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.white, 
    .font: UIFont(name: GetFontNameBold(), size: 40)! ],
    for: UIControl.State.normal)
```