# How to search through sub views of navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I have a small question...How to search through the sub views of navigation bar ? How can I get subviews of navigation bar ?

Comment: Please be clearer and post code to help us understand what you are trying?

Comment: elaborate on your question and complete it , quite ambigous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question properly then You can do this :

```
for (UIView *temp in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews)
{        
    if ([temp isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"is button !");

        UIButton *tempButton = (UIButton *)temp ;
    }
    else if ([temp isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to search through the navigation bar's subviews to change attributes of the title label. You can access the titleView of a viewcontroller's navigationItem and set it to a label you created with a custom font.

And example of this can be seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832036/change-the-navigation-bars-font) answer.

Another solution would be to set the font of the title by using the titleTextAttributes property of the navigation controllers UINavigationBar. more info [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UINavigationBar). This solution is probably the most correct way to do it, but it is only available in iOS 5 and up.

Comment: ya u are right but..I want to set two title and sub title in navigation bar..