# Crash in ios7 while setting font on navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I am using this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791762/ios-7-change-navigation-bar-title-font) to change the font and color of title in navigation bar. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832036/change-the-navigation-bars-font). Both of them run fine in ios8 but when i test in ios7 each time it crashes at "NSFontAttributeName". If i remove the code to set the font and only set the color , it works.

The crash message that I get is * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]

Any help would be appreciated. Hope my problem is clear.

Comment: Are you sure the custom font file is available in the bundle? It crashing because of a `nil` value for your font

Comment: the crash happens probably because your font has not been loaded and you try to insert a `nil` value directly. have you checked your font is loaded properly? is the font-name correct?

Comment: That was the issue ! damn silly of me @anil

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [UINavigationBar appearance];
[navBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"yourFont" size:15]];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it works fine for me in both IOS8 as well as IOS7
`

```
NSShadow * shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor];
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
[self.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:@"custom-color",
                                                 NSShadowAttributeName: shadow,
                                                 NSFontAttributeName: @"font-name",
                                                 }];`
```